# Threading: Waiting for window to open to do action

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have written a Window Manager for my program, which keeps certain windows open for the life of the Program (on background threads) (if the user wants them open). 
I just implemented an action for the contacts window. The problem is that, the action works when the window is already open, but if the action is invoked when the window isn't open yet, then the window opens, but the action is not carried out (pressing the button again will carry out the action).

the code:

```
private static SetupContacts _contactsWindow;
private static Thread _contactthread;

public static void ShowContact(repUserObject uo, ContactFormAction action, int contactID)
    {
        if (_contactsWindow == null)
            CreateContactThread(uo, contactID);

        // make sure it is still alive
        if (!_contactthread.IsAlive)
            CreateContactThread(uo, contactID);

        if (_contactsWindow != null)
        {
            _contactsWindow.BringToFront();
            _contactsWindow.Focus();
            switch (action)
            {
                case ContactFormAction.ViewContact:
                    if (contactID > 0)
                        _contactsWindow.LoadCustomer(contactID); // load the contact
                    break;

                case ContactFormAction.AddNewContact:
                    _contactsWindow.AddCustomer();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CreateContactThread(repUserObject uo, int contactID)
    {
        if (_contactthread == null || !_contactthread.IsAlive)
        {
            _contactthread = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                _contactsWindow = new SetupContacts(uo, contactID);
                _contactsWindow.CerberusContactScreenClosed += delegate { _contactsWindow = null; };
                _contactsWindow.CerberusContactHasBeenSaved += delegate(object sender, ContactBeenSavedEventArgs args)
                {
                    if (CerberusContactHasBeenSaved != null)
                        CerberusContactHasBeenSaved.Raise(sender, args);
                };
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                BonusSkins.Register();
                SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
                UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("iMaginary");
                Application.Run(_contactsWindow);
            });
            _contactthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _contactthread.Start();
        }
    }
```

What happens when the routine runs for the first time, (by calling ShowTime), that it hits the first if statement and goes to CreateContactThread() routine. That does it job, but when it returns, the _contactsWindow is still null. The next time the routine is called (ie, call by pressing the button the second time), it all works fine as the _contactWindow is not null.
How do i get it to do it all in one go ?

Comment: It's not generally advisable to have multiple UI threads: you're going to have to walk on eggshells to avoid cross-thread exceptions.. Why are these windows running on new threads?

Comment: Having said that, looks like your immediate problem is that `_contactsWindow` hasn't been created when you check for it in the main thread, because the new thread hasn't actually gotten a timeslice yet. You need to either poll for it, or have some way for the new thread to signal its readiness to the main thread.

Comment: thanks for the comments peter and blorgbeard. Basically what i want to do is in my app, is that the main app controls what windows are open via ShowDialog(), But there are several windows that i want the user to be able to keep open without locking up the main UI thread. That is why i thought that way may be a good way of doing it. Then what is a better way of doing it? using Show() on a global variable? or is there a better way?

Comment: Using Show() is no good. It initially works fine (the popup window is responsive, and both screens can be used correctly). but the problem is that if i open another window from the root form, then the popup window get locked. this is why i chose to use the threads as it solved that problem (the program i wrote has a lot of forms in it (150+) )

Answer (score 0):

I am in vehement agreement with commenter Blorgbeard, who advises that it's a bad idea to run more than one UI thread. The API itself works best when used in a single thread, and many of the kinds of actions and operations one might want to do in code with respect to the UI objects are most easily handled in a single thread, because doing so inherently ensures things happen in the order one expects (e.g. variables are initialized before being used).

That said, if for some reason you really must run your new window in a different thread, you can synchronize the two threads so that the initial thread cannot proceed until the new thread has gotten far enough for the operations you want to perform on the newly-initialized object to have a reasonable chance of success (including, of course, that object having been created in the first place).

There are lots of techniques for synchronizing threads, but I prefer the new `TaskCompletionSource<T>` object. It's simple to use, and if and when you update the code to use `async`/`await`, it will readily mesh with that.

For example:

```
public static void ShowContact(repUserObject uo, ContactFormAction action, int contactID)
{
    CreateContactThread(uo, contactID);

    if (_contactsWindow != null)
    {
        _contactsWindow.BringToFront();
        _contactsWindow.Focus();
        switch (action)
        {
            case ContactFormAction.ViewContact:
                if (contactID > 0)
                    _contactsWindow.LoadCustomer(contactID); // load the contact
                break;

            case ContactFormAction.AddNewContact:
                _contactsWindow.AddCustomer();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void CreateContactThread(repUserObject uo, int contactID)
{
    if (_contactthread == null || !_contactthread.IsAlive)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        _contactthread = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            _contactsWindow = new SetupContacts(uo, contactID);
            _contactsWindow.CerberusContactScreenClosed += delegate { _contactsWindow = null; };
            _contactsWindow.CerberusContactHasBeenSaved += delegate(object sender, ContactBeenSavedEventArgs args)
            {
                if (CerberusContactHasBeenSaved != null)
                    CerberusContactHasBeenSaved.Raise(sender, args);
            };

            _contactsWindow.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(true);
            };

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            BonusSkins.Register();
            SkinManager.EnableFormSkins();
            UserLookAndFeel.Default.SetSkinStyle("iMaginary");
            Application.Run(_contactsWindow);
        });
        _contactthread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        _contactthread.Start();

        tcs.Task.Wait();
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

- You had what appears to me to be redundant checks in your code. The `CreateContactThread()` method itself checks for `null` and `!IsAlive`, and restarts the thread if either of those are false. So in theory, by the time that method returns, the caller should be guaranteed that everything has been initialized as desired. And you should only have to call the method once. So I changed the code to do just that: call the method exactly once, and do so unconditionally (since the method will just do nothing if there is nothing to do).
- The calling thread will wait in the `CreateContactThread()` method after starting the new thread, until the new window's `Loaded` event has been raised. Of course, the window object itself has been created earlier than that, and you could in fact release the calling thread at that time. But it seems likely to me that you want the window object fully initialized before you start trying to do things to it. So I've delayed the synchronization to that point.
- As Blorgbeard has noted, one of the risks of running UI objects in multiple threads is that it's harder to access those objects without getting `InvalidOperationException`s. Even if it works, you should not really be accessing `_contactsWindow` outside of the thread where it was created, but the code above does just that (i.e. calls `BringToFront()`, `Focus()`, `LoadCustomer()`, and `AddCustomer()` from the original thread). I make no assurances that the code above is actually fully correct. Only that it addresses the primary synchronization issue that you are asking about.
- Speaking of other possible bugs, you probably have an unresolved race condition, in that the new contacts-form thread *might* be exiting just as you are checking its `IsAlive` property. If you check the property *just before* it exits, but then try to access the thread and/or the window after it has exited, your code is likely to do something bad (like crash with an exception). This is yet another example of something that would be a lot easier to address if all of your UI objects were being handled in a single thread.
- I admit that some of the above is speculative. It's impossible for me to say for sure how your code will behave without seeing [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But I feel the likelihood of all of the above being accurate and applicable is very high. :)